# Trie implementation

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, trie

Is there any speed- and cache-efficient implementations of trie in C/C++?
I know what a trie is, but I don't want reinvent the wheel, implementing it myself.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/simple-trie/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

if you are looking for an ANSI C implementation you can "steal" it from FreeBSD. The file you are looking for is called [radix.c](http://bxr.su/f/sys/net/radix.c). It's used for managing routing data in kernel.

Comment: @SashaN Link doesn't work.

Comment: try this link for radix.c : http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/net/radix.c

Answer (score 19):

I realize the question was about ready implementations, but for reference...

Before you jump on Judy you should have read "[A Performance Comparison of Judy to Hash Tables](http://www.nothings.org/computer/judy/)". Then googling the title will likely give you a lifetime of discussion and rebutals to read.

The one explicitly cache-conscious trie I know of is the [HAT-trie](http://crpit.com/confpapers/CRPITV62Askitis.pdf).

The HAT-trie, when implemented correctly, is very cool. However, for prefix search you need a sorting step on the hash buckets, which somewhat clashes with the idea of a prefix structure.

A somewhat simpler trie is the [burst-trie](http://www.cs.rmit.edu.au/~jz/fulltext/acmtois02.pdf) which essentially gives you an interpolation between a standard tree of some sort (like a BST) and a trie. I like it conceptually and it's much easier to implement.

Answer (score 7):

I've had good luck with [libTrie](http://wikipedia-clustering.speedblue.org/trie.php). It may not be specifically cache optimized but the performance has always been decent for my applications.

Answer (score 5):

GCC ships with a handful of data structures as part of its "Policy-based data structures". This includes a few trie implementations.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/pb_ds/trie_based_containers.html

Comment: Could you, please, provide a sample with `#include`? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Sample use of trie https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/testsuite/ext/pb_ds/example/trie_prefix_search.cc

Answer (score 4):

References,

- A [Double-Array Trie implementation](http://linux.thai.net/~thep/datrie/datrie.html) article (includes a `C` implementation)
- [TRASH](http://www.nada.kth.se/~snilsson/public/papers/trash/) - A dynamic LC-trie and hash data structure -- (a 2006 PDF reference describing a dynamic LC-trie used in the Linux kernel to implement address lookup in the IP routing table

Answer (score 4):

[Judy arrays](http://judy.sourceforge.net/): Very fast and memory efficient ordered sparse dynamic arrays for bits, integers and strings. Judy arrays are faster and more memory efficient than any binary-search-tree (incl. avl & red-black-trees).

Answer (score 3):

[Cedar](http://www.tkl.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~ynaga/cedar/#perf), [HAT-Trie](https://github.com/luikore/hat-trie), and [JudyArray](https://github.com/mpictor/judy-template) is quite awesome, you can find the benchmark [here](http://kokizzu.blogspot.com/2015/02/string-associative-array-benchmark.html).

[image: benchmark result]

Answer (score 2):

You can also try TommyDS at http://tommyds.sourceforge.net/

See the benchmarks page on the site for a speed comparison with nedtries and judy.

Comment: (FYI I'm the author of nedtries) Note that the benchmarks above used the C version of nedtries. The C++ version is about 15% faster and if I'm reading the graph right, would be only slightly slower than TommyDS's version if built as C++. That said, he has far lower overhead per node than I do. I deliberately go overboard in metadata to enable really deep assertion checking during debug operation :)

Answer (score 1):

Cache optimizations are something you'll probably are going to have to do, because you'll have to fit the data into a single cacheline which generally is something like 64 bytes (which will probably work if you start combining data, such as pointers). But it's tricky :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Burst Trie's](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~jz/fulltext/acmtois02.pdf) seem to be a bit more space efficient. I'm not sure how much cache-efficiency you can get out of any index since CPU-caches are so tiny. However, this kind of trie is plenty compact enough to keep large data sets in RAM (where a regular Trie would not).

I wrote a  Scala implementation of a burst trie that also incorporates some space-saving techniques that I found in GWT's type-ahead implementation.

https://github.com/nbauernfeind/scala-burst-trie

Comment: My downvote is unintentional and is now locked by StackOverflow. I do not know how to undo it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've had very good results (very good balance between performance and size) with marisa-trie compared to several TRIE implementations mentioned with my data set.

https://github.com/s-yata/marisa-trie/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my "fast" implementation for Trie, tested just in basic scenario:

```
#define ENG_LET 26

class Trie {
    class TrieNode {
    public:
        TrieNode* sons[ENG_LET];
        int strsInBranch;
        bool isEndOfStr;

        void print() {
            cout << "----------------" << endl;
            cout << "sons..";
            for(int i=0; i<ENG_LET; ++i) {
                if(sons[i] != NULL)
                    cout << " " << (char)('a'+i);
            }
            cout << endl;
            cout << "strsInBranch = " << strsInBranch << endl;
            cout << "isEndOfStr = " << isEndOfStr << endl;
            for(int i=0; i<ENG_LET; ++i) {
                if(sons[i] != NULL)
                    sons[i]->print();
            }

        }
        TrieNode(bool _isEndOfStr = false):isEndOfStr(_isEndOfStr), strsInBranch(0) {
            for(int i=0; i<ENG_LET; ++i) {
                sons[i] = NULL;
            }
        }
        ~TrieNode() {
            for(int i=0; i<ENG_LET; ++i) {
                delete sons[i];
                sons[i] = NULL;
            }
        }
    };

    TrieNode* head;
public:
    Trie() { head = new TrieNode();}
    ~Trie() { delete head; }
    void print() {
        cout << "Preorder Print : " << endl;
        head->print();
    }
    bool isExists(const string s) {
        TrieNode* curr = head;
        for(int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i) {
            int letIdx = s[i]-'a';
            if(curr->sons[letIdx] == NULL) {
                return false;
            }
            curr = curr->sons[letIdx];
        }

        return curr->isEndOfStr;
    }
    void addString(const string& s) {
        if(isExists(s))
            return;
        TrieNode* curr = head;
        for(int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i) {
            int letIdx = s[i]-'a';
            if(curr->sons[letIdx] == NULL) {
                curr->sons[letIdx] = new TrieNode();    
            }
            ++curr->strsInBranch;
            curr = curr->sons[letIdx];
        }
        ++curr->strsInBranch;
        curr->isEndOfStr = true;
    }
    void removeString(const string& s) {
        if(!isExists(s))
            return;
        TrieNode* curr = head;
        for(int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i) {
            int letIdx = s[i]-'a';

            if(curr->sons[letIdx] == NULL) {
                assert(false);
                return; //string not exists, will not reach here
            }
            if(curr->strsInBranch==1) {    //just 1 str that we want remove, remove the whole branch
                delete curr;
                return;
            }
            //more than 1 son
            --curr->strsInBranch;
            curr = curr->sons[letIdx];
        }
        curr->isEndOfStr = false;
    }

    void clear() {
        for(int i=0; i<ENG_LET; ++i) {
            delete head->sons[i];
            head->sons[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

};
```