# Can you tell which is super fast way to map string to integer

Tags: string, integer

I Have a key value pair(both key and value are static). Key is string and value is integer. We I get a string key I need to find value. Earlier I used hashmap but it is slow we I have large entry set. Can you tell which is super fast way to map string to integer.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap is a very efficient data structure for this task. It's unlikely that you'd be able to improve on the existing code.

However, this article may provide some insight - [Is it possible to map string to int faster than using hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141178/is-it-possible-to-map-string-to-int-faster-than-using-hashmap)