# Binary String to Hex c++

Tags: c++, binary, hex

When changing a Binary string to Hex, I could only do it to a certain size based off of the answers I found. But I want to change MASSIVE Binary strings into their complete Hex counterpart in a more efficient way than this which is the only way I've come across that does it completely:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < (binarySubVec.size() - 1); i++){
    string binToHex, tmp = "0000";
    for (size_t j = 0; j < binaryVecStr[i].size(); j += 4){
        tmp = binaryVecStr[i].substr(j, 4);
        if      (!tmp.compare("0000")) binToHex += "0";
        else if (!tmp.compare("0001")) binToHex += "1";
        else if (!tmp.compare("0010")) binToHex += "2";
        else if (!tmp.compare("0011")) binToHex += "3";
        else if (!tmp.compare("0100")) binToHex += "4";
        else if (!tmp.compare("0101")) binToHex += "5";
        else if (!tmp.compare("0110")) binToHex += "6";
        else if (!tmp.compare("0111")) binToHex += "7";
        else if (!tmp.compare("1000")) binToHex += "8";
        else if (!tmp.compare("1001")) binToHex += "9";
        else if (!tmp.compare("1010")) binToHex += "A";
        else if (!tmp.compare("1011")) binToHex += "B";
        else if (!tmp.compare("1100")) binToHex += "C";
        else if (!tmp.compare("1101")) binToHex += "D";
        else if (!tmp.compare("1110")) binToHex += "E";
        else if (!tmp.compare("1111")) binToHex += "F";
        else continue;
    }
    hexOStr << binToHex;
    hexOStr << " ";
}
```

Its thorough and absolute, but slow.

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: your code fail for binary not aligned to 4 bits...

Comment: can we assume input is multiple of 4 bits?

Comment: I did say _"MASSIVE Binary strings"_ -- And yes, the strings will always be multiples of 4

Comment: It has nothing to do with massivity of the binary numbers as 10000(2) = 10(16) not 80(16)

Comment: Stream in buffers of Nx4 8-bit characters. Forget that they're chars and treat the buffer as a `uint32_t *` then you can compare 32-bits at a time. MUCH faster than messing around with strings and characters.

Comment: Reserve space in the string of size()/4. Otherwize, use a stringstream

Comment: @AndyBrown good idea, I've put together solution, can you look it over if you see any problems?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE** Added comparison and benchmarks at the end

Here's another take, based on a perfect hash. The perfect hash was generated using `gperf` (like described here: [Is it possible to map string to int faster than using hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141178/is-it-possible-to-map-string-to-int-faster-than-using-hashmap/16141214?s=5|0.3571#16141214)).

I've further optimized by moving function local statics out of the way and marking `hexdigit()` and `hash()` as `constexpr`. This removes unnecessary any initialization overhead and gives the compiler full room for optimization/

#### I don't expect things to get much faster than this.

You *could* try reading e.g. 1024 nibbles at a time if possible, and give the compiler a chance to vectorize the operations using AVX/SSE instruction sets. *(I have not inspected the generated code to see whether this would happen.)*

The full sample code to translate `std::cin` to `std::cout` in streaming mode is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char buffer[4096];
    while (std::cin.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)), std::cin.gcount())
    {
        size_t got = std::cin.gcount();
        char* out = buffer;

        for (auto it = buffer; it < buffer+got; it += 4)
            *out++ = Perfect_Hash::hexchar(it);

        std::cout.write(buffer, got/4);
    }
}
```

Here's the `Perfect_Hash` class, slightly redacted and extended with the `hexchar` lookup. Note that it does validate input in `DEBUG` builds using the `assert`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/714721b3ab828d3b)</kbd>**

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

class Perfect_Hash {
    /* C++ code produced by gperf version 3.0.4 */
    /* Command-line: gperf -L C++ -7 -C -E -m 100 table  */
    /* Computed positions: -k'1-4' */

    /* maximum key range = 16, duplicates = 0 */
  private:
      static constexpr unsigned char asso_values[] = {
          27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27,
          27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 15, 7,  3,  1,  0,  27,
          27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27,
          27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27,
          27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27};
      template <typename It>
      static constexpr unsigned int hash(It str)
      {
          return 
              asso_values[(unsigned char)str[3] + 2] + asso_values[(unsigned char)str[2] + 1] +
              asso_values[(unsigned char)str[1] + 3] + asso_values[(unsigned char)str[0]];
      }

      static constexpr char hex_lut[] = "???????????fbead9c873625140";
  public:
#ifdef DEBUG
    template <typename It>
    static char hexchar(It binary_nibble)
    {
        assert(Perfect_Hash::validate(binary_nibble)); // for DEBUG only
        return hex_lut[hash(binary_nibble)]; // no validation!
    }
#else
    template <typename It>
    static constexpr char hexchar(It binary_nibble)
    {
        return hex_lut[hash(binary_nibble)]; // no validation!
    }
#endif
    template <typename It>
    static bool validate(It str)
    {
        static constexpr std::array<char, 4> vocab[] = {
            {{'?', '?', '?', '?'}}, {{'?', '?', '?', '?'}}, {{'?', '?', '?', '?'}},
            {{'?', '?', '?', '?'}}, {{'?', '?', '?', '?'}}, {{'?', '?', '?', '?'}},
            {{'?', '?', '?', '?'}}, {{'?', '?', '?', '?'}}, {{'?', '?', '?', '?'}},
            {{'?', '?', '?', '?'}}, {{'?', '?', '?', '?'}},
            {{'1', '1', '1', '1'}}, {{'1', '0', '1', '1'}},
            {{'1', '1', '1', '0'}}, {{'1', '0', '1', '0'}},
            {{'1', '1', '0', '1'}}, {{'1', '0', '0', '1'}},
            {{'1', '1', '0', '0'}}, {{'1', '0', '0', '0'}},
            {{'0', '1', '1', '1'}}, {{'0', '0', '1', '1'}},
            {{'0', '1', '1', '0'}}, {{'0', '0', '1', '0'}},
            {{'0', '1', '0', '1'}}, {{'0', '0', '0', '1'}},
            {{'0', '1', '0', '0'}}, {{'0', '0', '0', '0'}},
        }; 
        int key = hash(str);

        if (key <= 26 && key >= 0)
            return std::equal(str, str+4, vocab[key].begin());
        else
            return false;
    }
};

constexpr unsigned char Perfect_Hash::asso_values[];
constexpr char Perfect_Hash::hex_lut[];

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char buffer[4096];
    while (std::cin.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)), std::cin.gcount())
    {
        size_t got = std::cin.gcount();
        char* out = buffer;

        for (auto it = buffer; it < buffer+got; it += 4)
            *out++ = Perfect_Hash::hexchar(it);

        std::cout.write(buffer, got/4);
    }
}
```

Demo output for e.g. `od -A none -t o /dev/urandom | tr -cd '01' | dd bs=1 count=4096 | ./test`

> 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

## BENCHMARKS

I came up with three different approaches:

1. **[naive.cpp (no hacks, no libraries)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57136925288d85bd)**; Live disassembly [on **Godbolt**](http://goo.gl/bXh0m3)
2. [**spirit.cpp** (Trie)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9e7dbde1fb1b978); <strike>Live</strike> disassembly [on pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10664535/)
3. and [this answer: **perfect.cpp** hash](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a671172084058a9) based; Live disassembly [on **Godbolt**](http://goo.gl/T3uE2V)

In order to do some comparisons, I've

- compiled them all with the same compiler (GCC 4.9) and flags (`-O3 -march=native -g0 -DNDEBUG`)
- optimized input/output so it doesn't read by 4 chars/write single characters
- created a large input file (1 Gigabyte)

Here are the results:

[image]

- Surprisingly, the `naive` approach from the first answer does rather well
- Spirit does really badly here; it nets 3.4MB/s so that the whole file would take at 294 seconds (!!!). We've left it off the charts
- The average throughputs are ~720MB/s for **naive.cpp** and ~1.14GB/s for**perfect.cpp**
- This makes the perfect hash approach roughly 50% faster than the naive approach.

> ***Summary** I'd say the naive approach was plenty good [as I posted it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29210329/85371) on whim 10 hours ago. If you really want high throughput, the perfect hash is a nice start, but consider hand-rolling a SIMD based solution

Comment: I've further optimized by moving function local statics out of the way and marking `hexdigit()` and `hash()` as `constexpr`. This removes unnecessary any initialization overhead and gives the compiler full room for optimization/

Comment: As a side note, for super-duper performance I have it on [authority](http://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial) hand-tuned SIMD can squeeze a few more drops out.

Comment: What stops this being optimal is your `hash()` call inside the tight loop. It's doing lots of 8-bit fetches and arithmetic. Compare this to the single machine `div` instruction inside @TonyK's implementation.

Comment: Taking on board the extensive use of `constexpr` I compiled this with `-O3` and disassembled the result. It's a lot closer than I thought. If I'm following it correctly (not easy with optimised output) then your `hash()` is actually resolving to 2 `movzbl` instructions which does make it very fast. I retract my prior comment.

Comment: @AndyBrown Kudos for that. I've added comparative benchmarks to may answer now, including live links to ***color-coded disassemblies*** (e.g. **[this one](http://goo.gl/Gzi445)**) on Godbolt Compiler Explorer. It does seem to be pretty fast. At least it's faster than the naive approach :)

Answer (score 5):

something like this maybe

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::hex << std::stoll("100110110010100100111101010001001101100101010110000101111111111",NULL,  2) << std::endl;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << std::stoll("100110110010100100111101010001001101100101010110000101111111111", NULL, 2);
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And how is this going to support _"MASSIVE Binary strings"_? (Emphasis not mine)

Comment: This was one of the solutions I was on about that I found -- P.S. Cheers for not taking credit for the emphasis :P

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE2** See **[here for my perfect-hash based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29214966/85371)**. This solution would have my preference because

- It compiles a lot faster
- It has more predictable runtime (there are zero allocations going on, since all data is static)

> **EDIT** indeed now benchmarking has shown the perfect hash solution to be roughly ***340 x faster*** than the Spirit approach.  **[See here: [image]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29214966/85371)**

**UPDATE**

Added a **[Trie-based solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)**.

The lookup-table here uses Boost Spirit's internal Trie implementation for fast lookup.

Of course replace `out` with e.g. a vector `back_inserter` or a `ostreambuf_iterator<char>` into your string stream if you prefer. Right now it never allocates even 4 characters (although of course the lookup table is allocated, once).

You can also trivially replace the input iterators with what ever input range you have available, without changing a line of the rest of the code.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76fd1ed13c8b028d)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> out(std::cout);

    qi::symbols<char, char> lookup_table;
    lookup_table.add
        ("0000", '0')
        ("0001", '1')
        ("0010", '2')
        ("0011", '3')
        ("0100", '4')
        ("0101", '5')
        ("0110", '6')
        ("0111", '7')
        ("1000", '8')
        ("1001", '9')
        ("1010", 'a')
        ("1011", 'b')
        ("1100", 'c')
        ("1101", 'd')
        ("1110", 'e')
        ("1111", 'f')
        ;

    boost::spirit::istream_iterator bof(std::cin), eof;

    if (qi::parse(bof, eof, +lookup_table [ *boost::phoenix::ref(out) = qi::_1 ]))
        return 0;
    else
        return 255;
}
```

When testing with some random data like `od -A none -t o /dev/urandom | tr -cd '01' | dd bs=1 count=4096 | ./test` you get

> 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

---

Old, *elementary* answer:

#### *Read input from a stream and output a single character each 4 bytes.*

Here's the gist:

```
char nibble[4];
while (std::cin.read(nibble, 4))
{
    std::cout << "0123456789abcdef"[
            (nibble[0]!='0')*8 +
            (nibble[1]!='0')*4 +
            (nibble[2]!='0')*2 +
            (nibble[3]!='0')*1
        ];
}
```

You could make the conversion a lookup table indeed. Don't use a map as it's tree based and will end up chasing a lot of pointers. However, `boost::flat_map` could be fine.

Comment: Added a trie-based solution that never allocates more even 4 bytes in memory. Input and output are streaming. I tested the lookup table now. See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76fd1ed13c8b028d)**

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would do it:

1. Find the smallest positive integer `n` such that these integers all have different remainders modulo `n`:

   0x30303030
   0x30303031
   0x30303130
   0x30303131
   0x30313030
   0x30313031
   0x30313130
   0x30313131
   0x31303030
   0x31303031
   0x31303130
   0x31303131
   0x31313030
   0x31313031
   0x31313130
   0x31313131

These are the ASCII representations of "0000","0001" etc. I have listed them in order, assuming that your machine is big-endian; if it is little-endian, the representation of e.g. "0001" will be 0x31303030, not 0x30303031. You only have to do this once. `n` will not be very large -- I would expect it to be less than 100.

2. Build a table `char HexChar[n]` with `HexChar[0x30303030 % n] = '0', HexChar[0x30303031 % n] = '1'` etc. (or `HexChar[0x31303030 % n] = '1'` etc. if your machine is little-endian).

Now the conversion is lightning-fast (I am assuming `sizeof (int) = 4`):

```
unsigned int const* s = binaryVecStr[a].c_str();
for (size_t i = 0; i < binaryVecStr[a].size(); i += 4, s++)
    hexOStr << HexChar[*s % n];
```

Comment: Nice one with the mod solution. When I was thinking about the 32-bits-at-a-time comparison I also tried to come up with an arithmetic/bitshift method of reducing the comparisons to a table. Never thought of mod though. I like it.

Comment: This gave me the idea, your idea is conceptually close to a perfect hash. I [went and implemented that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29214966/85371): the LUT is 26 items - that's not a lot of overhead) and all machinery is `constexpr`.

Comment: Your magic number 'n' is 18. With only a '%' in the tight loop I can't see how this could get any faster. In x86 assembly language the remainder is returned as part of the `div` instruction so this method ought to be optimal.

Answer (score 4):

I have this strange feeling that I must be missing something important about the question here. At first glance, it seems like this should work:

```
template <class RanIt, class OutIt>
void make_hex(RanIt b, RanIt e, OutIt o) {
    static const char rets[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    if ((e-b) %4 != 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("Length must be a multiple of 4");

    while (b != e) {
        int index = 
            ((*(b + 0) - '0') << 3) |
            ((*(b + 1) - '0') << 2) |
            ((*(b + 2) - '0') << 1) |
            ((*(b + 3) - '0') << 0);
        *o++ = rets[index];
        b += 4;
    }
}
```

At least offhand, this seems like it should just about as fast as anything could be--it looks to me like it closely approaches the minimum of processing on each input necessary to get to the output.

To maximize speed, it does minimize error checking on the input to (and perhaps below) the bare minimum. You could certainly assure that each character in the input was a '0' or a '1' before depending on the result of the subtraction. Alternatively, you could quite easily use `(*(b + 0) != '0') << 3` to treat `0` as 0 and anything else as a `1`. Likewise, you could use: `(*(b + 0) == '1') << 3` to get `1` treated as 1, and anything else as 0.

The code does avoid dependencies between the 4 computations needed to compute each `index` value, so it should be possible for a smart compiler to do those computations in parallel.

Since it works only with iterators, it avoids making extra copies of the input data, as (for example) almost anything using `substr` can (especially with an implementation of `std::string` that doesn't include the short string optimization).

In any case, using this would look something like this:

```
int main() { 
    char input[] = "0000000100100011010001010110011110001001101010111100110111101111";

    make_hex(input, input+64, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
}
```

Since it does use iterators, it could just as easily (for only one obvious example) take input from an istreambuf_iterator to process data directly from a file. That's rarely the fastest possible way to do though--you'll usually get better speed using `istream::read` to read a large chunk, and `ostream::write` to write a large chunk at once. This wouldn't need to affect the actual conversion code though--you'd just pass it pointers into your input and output buffers, and it would use them as iterators.

Comment: Your version is logically close to my "naive". But somehow it's as fast as the perfect hash solution. I'll look at why later. +1 from me for now

Comment: How can you change the input for `char input[] = ...` ?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work.

```
std::vector<char> binaryVecStr = { '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0' };

string binToHex;
binToHex.reserve(binaryVecStr.size()/4);
for (uint32_t * ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(binaryVecStr.data()); ptr < reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(binaryVecStr.data()) + binaryVecStr.size() / 4; ++ptr) {
    switch (*ptr) {
        case 0x30303030:
            binToHex += "0";
            break;
        case 0x31303030:
            binToHex += "1";
            break;
        case 0x30313030:
            binToHex += "2";
            break;
        case 0x31313030:
            binToHex += "3";
            break;
        case 0x30303130:
            binToHex += "4";
            break;
        case 0x31303130:
            binToHex += "5";
            break;
        case 0x30313130:
            binToHex += "6";
            break;
        case 0x31313130:
            binToHex += "7";
            break;
        case 0x30303031:
            binToHex += "8";
            break;
        case 0x31303031:
            binToHex += "9";
            break;
        case 0x30313031:
            binToHex += "A";
            break;
        case 0x31313031:
            binToHex += "B";
            break;
        case 0x30303131:
            binToHex += "C";
            break;
        case 0x31303131:
            binToHex += "D";
            break;
        case 0x30313131:
            binToHex += "E";
            break;
        case 0x31313131:
            binToHex += "F";
            break;
        default:
            // invalid input
            binToHex += "?";
    }
}

std::cout << binToHex;
```

Beware, is uses few assumtpions:

1) char has 8 bits (not true on all platforms)

2) it requires little endian (meaning it works at least on x86, x86_64)

It assumes that binaryVecStr is std::vector, but would work with string as well. It assumes that `binaryVecStr.size() % 4 == 0`

Comment: You still reserve memory for the full buffer, which is going to be a stopper if stream sizes grow large (larger than available memory, e.g.)

Comment: I did that and benchmarked it against my solution (see my answer for more results). When I used your code optimized for streaming IO and in the same testbed, it [ran at ~314MB/s](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10665013/). At least the output was _correct_ without fixes (I just made the hex digits lowercase so I could checksum the results to verify correctness). Here's the precise code used for the benchmark: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/793f68e7ab48c4d8)**

Comment: Ok, 1.14GB/s is quite impressive. And in regards to my solution, I'm little disappointed that it's that slow :/

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd guess it's the branchiness: http://goo.gl/2Xg1Hw. It's not that slow though :) Most solutions were considerably slower

Answer (score 3):

This is the fastest I could come up with:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char buffer[4096];
    while (std::cin.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)), std::cin.gcount() > 0) {
        size_t got = std::cin.gcount();
        char* out = buffer;

        for (const char* it = buffer; it < buffer + got; it += 4) {
            unsigned long r;
            r  = it[3];
            r += it[2] * 2;
            r += it[1] * 4;
            r += it[0] * 8;
            *out++ = "0123456789abcdef"[r - 15*'0'];
        }

        std::cout.write(buffer, got / 4);
    }
}
```

It's faster than anything else on this question, according to @sehe's benchmarks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a binary decision tree:

```
string binToHex;
for (size_t i = 0; i < binaryVecStr[a].size(); i += 4) {
    string tmp = binaryVecStr[a].substr(i, 4);
    if (tmp[0] == '0') {
        if (tmp[1] == '0') {
            if (tmp[2] == '0') {
                if tmp[3] == '0') {
                    binToHex += "0";
                } else {
                    binToHex += "1";
                }
            } else {
                if tmp[3] == '0') {
                    binToHex += "2";
                } else {
                    binToHex += "3";
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (tmp[2] == '0') {
                if tmp[3] == '0') {
                    binToHex += "4";
                } else {
                    binToHex += "5";
                }
            } else {
                if tmp[3] == '0') {
                    binToHex += "6";
                } else {
                    binToHex += "7";
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (tmp[1] == '0') {
            if (tmp[2] == '0') {
                if tmp[3] == '0') {
                    binToHex += "8";
                } else {
                    binToHex += "9";
                }
            } else {
                if tmp[3] == '0') {
                    binToHex += "A";
                } else {
                    binToHex += "B";
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (tmp[2] == '0') {
                if tmp[3] == '0') {
                    binToHex += "C";
                } else {
                    binToHex += "D";
                }
            } else {
                if tmp[3] == '0') {
                    binToHex += "E";
                } else {
                    binToHex += "F";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
hexOStr << binToHex;
```

You might also want to consider a more compact representation
of the same decision tree, such as

```
string binToHex;
for (size_t i = 0; i < binaryVecStr[a].size(); i += 4) {
    string tmp = binaryVecStr[a].substr(i, 4);
    binToHex += (tmp[0] == '0' ?
                    (tmp[1] == '0' ?
                        (tmp[2] == '0' ?
                            (tmp[3] == '0' ? "0" : "1") :
                            (tmp[3] == '0' ? "2" : "3")) :
                        (tmp[2] == '0' ?
                            (tmp[3] == '0' ? "4" : "5") :
                            (tmp[3] == '0' ? "6" : "7"))) :
                    (tmp[1] == '0' ?
                        (tmp[2] == '0' ?
                            (tmp[3] == '0' ? "8" : "9") :
                            (tmp[3] == '0' ? "A" : "B")) :
                        (tmp[2] == '0' ?
                            (tmp[3] == '0' ? "C" : "D") :
                            (tmp[3] == '0' ? "E" : "F"))));
}
hexOStr << binToHex;
```

---

**Update:** In the vein of the ASCII-to-integer solutions:

```
unsigned int nibble = static_cast<unsigned int*>(buffer);
nibble &= 0x01010101;     // 0x31313131 --> 0x01010101
nibble |= (nibble >> 15); // 0x01010101 --> 0x01010303
nibble |= (nibble >> 6);  // 0x01010303 --> 0x0105070C
char* hexDigit = hexDigitTable[nibble & 15];
```

The contents of `hexDigitTable` (of type `char[16]`) would depend on whether
you are on a little-endian or big-endian machine.

Comment: Using this test program I've benchmarked this solution at ~307MB/s. Of course the string construction in the loop would have slowed it down unnecessarily. See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9311e58e5233b25b)** (and the disassembly http://goo.gl/KYvUxb)

Comment: @sehe This is a far less ambitious answer than yours, that's for sure! I just set out to do one thing, which was to reduce the number of "ifs" executed per loop without really rethinking the program's logic. A small, quick optimization. Changing the way the string is built would also be a good thing to do. Where did you do the benchmark?

Comment: On my workstation. I'm currently fixing a bug in the last-input block handling (didn't notice because 4 GB is a multiple of 4 KB)

Answer (score 2):

As for a simple way to do this, i think that this one is pretty neat:

```
std::string bintxt_2_hextxt(const std::string &bin)
{
    std::stringstream reader(bin);
    std::stringstream result;

    while (reader)
    {
        std::bitset<8> digit;
        reader >> digit;
        result << std::hex << digit.to_ulong();
    }

    return result.str();
}
```

I don't know from where your data should be readed so I've used a `std::string` as input data; but if it is from a text file or a data stream it shouldn't be a headache to change the `reader` to be a `std::ifstream`.

Beware! I don't know what could happen if the stream characters aren't divisible by 8 and also I haven't tested the performance of this code.

<kbd>[Live example](http://ideone.com/2NM0MQ)</kbd>

Comment: As written this has several problems. The throughput is roughly 8.5MB/s, you can compare it in my answer. I used this to benchmark: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45b5064660f5dd3c)**. See if you can find the problems fixed (aside from favouring streaming) :)

Comment: @sehe is always a pleasure to learn how to improve a code, thanks a lot (and thanks for helping instead of downvoting) :D

Answer (score 1):

I think use Trie Tree or sth else is too complex, I'd rather choose some costly calculation, but the algorithm behind seemed more reasonable and tidy: reverse-scan and grouping 4 elements.

But my solution below is still strong-robust and functional, she can deal with long binary string, and with checking code and removing prefix-0 function:

```
string bstohs(const string& bs) {
    string hs = {};
    auto c = bs.rbegin();
    auto end = bs.rend();
    if (bs.rfind("0b", 0) == 0) {
        end -= 2;
    }
    int localSum = 0;
    while (end - c > 3) {
        localSum = (*c - '0') + ((*(c + 1) - '0') << 1) + ((*(c + 2) - '0') << 2) + ((*(c + 3) - '0') << 3);
        hs = (localSum > 9 ? string(1, 'a' + localSum - 10) : to_string(localSum)) + hs;
        c += 4;
    }
    localSum = 0;
    for (auto lst = c; end - lst > 0; lst++) {
        if (*lst != '0') {
            localSum += ((*lst - '0') << (lst - c));
        }
    }
    hs = to_string(localSum) + hs;
    return "0x" + hs.erase(0, min(hs.find_first_not_of('0'), hs.size() - 1));
}
```

Here is test main func:

```
int main(){
    string bs = "0b";
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); 
    int test_time, test_max_len;
    cout << "input test time: ";
    cin >> test_time;
    cout << "input test max len: ";
    cin >> test_max_len;
    for (int i = 0; i < test_time; i++) {
        int test_len = rand() % test_max_len;
        bs += "1";
        for (int j = 1; j < test_len; j++) {
            bs += to_string(rand() % 2);
        }
        cout << "test case " << i << "\nraw bs: " << bs << "\nbin len: " << bs.size() - 2 << "\nnow hs: " << bstohs(bs) << endl;
        bs = "0b";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

a test case:

```
input test time: 3
input test max len: 400
test case 0
raw bs: 0b1111000001010110010011101010111110001101111101001101000110111111000110011000111000001100111101010111010010000111011001000010100110010100001000101001010001111111010010111111111000000101100110100000000101110111110000110100011001100111111100101011101111010000001101001000011000110110011000011000110110001101010011000001111101111010010010100001010100010110010
bin len: 355
now hs: 0x782b2757c6fa68df8cc7067aba43b214ca114a3fa5ff02cd00bbe1a333f95de81a431b30c6c6a60fbd250a8b2
test case 1
raw bs: 0b110111101010110011001110000110001101010100011011100111000000000111010011000100000011110010100100001101111000100010011110001010100000101010001101011001110111010010001100111011101010100010000110011111011110100010110100010000010010001011111000101110101100110010111010001111010101110011111110
bin len: 288
now hs: 0xdeacce18d51b9c01d3103ca437889e2a0a8d67748ceea8867de8b44122f8baccba3d5cfe
test case 2
raw bs: 0b11010001010111100010001010100111011010111110001111011100000111111011001010110010011011110101001111011
bin len: 101
now hs: 0x1a2bc454ed7c7b83f6564dea7b
```

environment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
```